# what is the difference between imageExtent and bounding box?

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am asking about the definition of imageExtent and bounding box in openlayers ?. I saw these words in other type of mapping library like leaflet.  I did not found a real definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an answer in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240979/difference-between-bounding-box-envelope-extent-bounds

If you are dealing with rotated images you will need to know whether the extent is that of the image before rotation (shown in blue) or the bounding extent (shown in green) of the rotated (red) image.  For example, a KML ground overlay is defined by the extent of the image before rotation, but you may find images where the extent is given as the outer extent after rotation, similar to the extent of a rotated view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, my pb principal is that i have an image (projection 'EPSG:4326') png (green one) with extent: [minX, minY, maxX, maxY] and i need to rotate it (red on) in openlayers. 

I saw this response from you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55356335/add-a-rotated-satellite-image-on-the-map-using-openlayers-5
but i did  not understand bl_longitude and tr_longitude in the response so i asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69890774/how-to-rotate-static-image-in-openlayers. Any idea please ?